# How to download a part of a large file from Drive API using Python script with range header option

Tags: python, download, http-headers, google-drive-api, partial

based on 
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads#partial_download

I have created a function, but I cannot get it to work.
How should I pass a range option to the headers?

```
resp, content = service._http.request(download_url, headers={'Range': 'bytes=0-299'})


def download_file(service, file_id):
  drive_file = service.files().get(fileId=file_id).execute()
  download_url = drive_file.get('downloadUrl')
  title = drive_file.get('title')
  originalFilename = drive_file.get('originalFilename')
  if download_url:
      resp, content = service._http.request(download_url, headers={'Range': 'bytes=0-299'})    
      if resp.status == 200:
         file = 'tmp.mp4'
         with open(file, 'wb') as f:
             while True:
              tmp = content.read()
              if not tmp:
                  break
              f.write(tmp)
      return title, file
    else:
      print 'An error occurred: %s' % resp
      return None
  else:
    return None
```

I'm getting:

> An error occurred: {'status': '206', 'alternate-protocol':
>   '443:quic,p=0.02', 'content-length': '300',
>   'access-control-allow-headers': 'Accept, Accept-Language,
>   Authorization, Cache-Control, Content-Disposition, Content-Encoding,
>   Content-Language, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Range,
>   Content-Type, Date, GData-Version, Host, If-Match, If-Modified-Since,
>   If-None-Match, If-Unmodified-Since, Origin, OriginToken, Pragma,
>   Range, Slug, Transfer-Encoding, X-ClientDetails, X-GData-Client,
>   X-GData-Key, X-Goog-AuthUser, X-Goog-PageId,
>   X-Goog-Encode-Response-If-Executable, X-Goog-Correlation-Id,
>   X-Goog-Request-Info, X-Goog-Experiments, x-goog-iam-role,
>   x-goog-iam-authorization-token, X-Goog-Spatula, X-Goog-Upload-Command,
>   X-Goog-Upload-Content-Disposition, X-Goog-Upload-Content-Length,
>   X-Goog-Upload-Content-Type, X-Goog-Upload-File-Name,
>   X-Goog-Upload-Offset, X-Goog-Upload-Protocol, X-Goog-Visitor-Id,
>   X-HTTP-Method-Override, X-JavaScript-User-Agent, X-Pan-Versionid,
>   X-Origin, X-Referer, X-Upload-Content-Length, X-Upload-Content-Type,
>   X-Use-HTTP-Status-Code-Override, X-YouTube-VVT, X-YouTube-Page-CL,
>   X-YouTube-Page-Timestamp', 'content-disposition':
>   'attachment;filename="1981-0930 Public Program, Day 7, Part 1,
>   Vishuddhi Chakra,
>   NYC.mpg";filename*=UTF-8\'\'1981-0930%20Public%20Program%2C%20Day%207%2C%20Part%201%2C%20Vishuddhi%20Chakra%2C%20NYC.mpg',
>   'access-control-allow-credentials': 'false', 'expires': 'Sun, 28 Dec
>   2014 09:09:35 GMT', 'server': 'UploadServer ("Built on Dec 19 2014
>   10:24:45 (1419013485)")', 'content-range': 'bytes 0-299/1885163442',
>   'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0', 'date': 'Sun, 28 Dec 2014
>   09:09:35 GMT', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
>   'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET,OPTIONS', 'content-type':
>   'video/mpeg'}

Thank you

Comment: So what problems are you observing...?

Comment: I'm getting 206 (see my edit), thank you

Comment: I found a mistake, 206 is OK :) so it should be `if resp.status == 206:`

Comment: Right: 206 means "partial content" -- **exactly** what you asked for!

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
  resp, content = service._http.request(download_url, headers={'Range': 'bytes=0-299'})
```

is correct